# How to install new WebView version in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-webview, react-native-cli

```
react-native-webview": "^11.21.2"
```

this is version in my project

I need to install Latest version of WebView in react native

```
react-native-webview:11.26.0
```

but whenever I try to install this

```
npm i react-native-webview@11.26.0 or npm install react-native-webview@latest
```

it's give me a error like this

```
npm install react-native-webview@latest 
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react@7.12.4 requires a peer of eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-native@3.6.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4 || ^5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dp312\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-15T17_01_21_473Z-debug.log
```

**So how can I install a latest version of webview in react native**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the below command in npm :

```
npm install react-native-webview@11.26.0 --legacy-peer-deps
```

Or, delete package.lock.json and node_modules folder
then run,

> npm i -f

then run

> npm install

Comment: npm install react-native-webview@11.26.0 --legacy-peer-deps it also give me error

Comment: try by using yarn

Comment: I'm try yarn it give me error like this::error fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Comment: react-native-webview": "^11.21.2"

Comment: I am asking a version of node also react-native

Comment: in project "react-native": "0.60.5",
node:v14.18.1
react-native-cli: 2.0.1

Comment: do do, npm i -f

Answer (score 0):

I tried this "npm install react-native-webview@11.26.0 --legacy-peer-deps" and it worked perfectly

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35602789)